# How can I save the state of a React.Component on submit without reseting it to the default?

Tags: reactjs, events, react-router

My idea is similar to a voting system: some blocks with a name, a number, and a button.
When I press the button the number is incremented, +1. The names come from an array in the state. How I call my component, being createAPP just a setState:

```
<AppForm handleCreate={this.createAPP} />
```

I am using react-router to do the routing:

```
<Link to="/">Home</Link>
<Route
    exact path="/"
    component={ListOfFrameworks}
/>
```

I want to place a textbox where I can type another name and it will create a similar box to the other boxes, with the same functionality.

I was using a form that onSubmit it stores to the parent state another name.
It draws everything correctly but then the page refreshes and resets to the original array.

```
<form onSubmit={() => this.submit} >
```

My submit function:

```
submit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.handleCreate(this.refs.name.value);
    this.refs.name.value = "";
}
```

How can I keep the page without refreshing, or keep the state after refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preventDefault()` method inside `onSubmit` method to prevent default behaviior

```
onSubmit(e){
  e.preventDefault()
}
```

Comment: this doesnt prevent what im saying.

Comment: @BlueDi The `onSubmit` function is not even called. It should be `<form onSubmit={() => this.submit()} >`
`

Comment: @BlueDi Why do you think so? They are needed, then only `this.submit` function will be called.

Comment: yeah my bad, i changed from passing the function to calling it with =>.
The correct way is:
(e) => this.submit(e)

Answer (score 0):

In your `onSubmit` function, add a call to `event.preventDefault()`

```
function mySubmitFunction(evt) {
  evt.preventDefault();
  // ...
}
```

Comment: this doesnt prevent what im saying.